# need help in simple java project

Tags: java

I am just beginning java and am having difficulites solving this, it is from my textbook, I would prefer if someone was able to solve it with just strings,loops, and if statments if possible. I am not familiar with "for" statments yet. I have tried it but am just puzzled on where to go after my code.

here is the question:

Create a Cities app that will allow you to enter the name of cities until you enter ‘stop’. Once ‘stop’ is entered, the app will display the number of cities entered and will display the name of the city with the most characters.

For example, if you enter Halifax, Moncton, and Charlottetown, it should tell the user that 3 cities were entered and the name of the city with the most letters is: Charlottetown

I tried a loop, but am just puzzled.

here is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cities;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author dtm600744
 */
public class Cities {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String citylist;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Name of city: ");
            citylist = input.next();

        } while (!citylist.equals("stop"));

        System.out.print(citylist);
    }
}
```

Comment: While you're reading input, you'll want to track two things: the name of the longest-named city, and the total number of cities. If you read a new city in, you don't have to keep track of it forever, but instead just compare it to your current results. A `for` loop isn't needed, but note that a `for` and a `while` loop are semantically the same thing, just written slightly different (`for` has 3 expressions).

Comment: You are not storing the input in a `List<String>`, you just overwrite the input in each loop because you are using a single variable.

Comment: `String citylist;` is a single `String`. Why did you call it a list?

Comment: @f1sh while the variable name is admittedly misleading, the problem's requirements don't necessitate a `List`. (Edit: Was a little overzealous on the tag there @Elliott)

Comment: @Rogue I'm aware of that. Still would not call the longest city name a citylist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a `count` that you increase monotonically everytime the user enters a valid city (one that isn't the word *stop*). You also need to keep track of the longest city name. I would use an infinite loop. Read a city name, check if it is *stop* (if so, end the loop) otherwise check if the new city name is longer than the longest city name if so it is the new longest city name. Increment the counter and repeat. Like,

```
int count = 0;
String longestCityName = "";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Name of city: ");
    String cityName = input.nextLine().trim();
    if (cityName.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
        break;
    }
    if (cityName.length() > longestCityName.length()) {
        longestCityName = cityName;
    }
    count++;
}
if (count > 0) {
    System.out.printf("%d cities were entered and the name of the city " 
            + "with the most letters is: %s", count,
            longestCityName);
} else {
    System.out.println("You didn't enter any cities");
}
```

Which I tested with your sample input (and *stop*) like

```
Name of city: Halifax
Name of city: Moncton
Name of city: Charlottetown
Name of city: stop
3 cities were entered and the name of the city with the most letters is: Charlottetown
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add some variables and compare the Input.

If you dont need all Citys in the end you can leave the variable Citylist but it would be better by naming it like currentCity etc.

After reading the new city you should compare the String like

```
private int longestNumber;
private String longestWord;

//inside do-while loop
if(cityList.length > longestNumber) longestWord = cityList;
```

Also take a second int variable for counting city`s, than you can do variable++ everytime a city is added inside the loop :D